# string return type in c++ does not return output

Tags: c++

This code is part of a larger program, i have to pass a string to a function and get a string back but i am having issues with the return type. Why is the following code not generating output **Trib 98**

P.S newbie here, hope the code posting format is correct

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string Platin(string x)
 {string ans = x + " 98" ;
    return ans; }

int main()
{Platin("Trib");}
```

Comment: You never output anything...

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/basic_io/

Comment: Try `string someVarName = Platin("Trib");`.

Comment: call like this inside your `main` method `cout<<Platin("Trib");`

Comment: @Rustam: http://powerfield-software.com/?p=829 :-)

Comment: @Rustam ,this is C++ not C

Comment: @Rustam What does `printf()` has to do with the preprocessor?

Answer (score 3):

The call to Platin in main is returning a string, but you never do anything with it.  Change `int main` to

```
int main()
{
    cout << Platin("Trib") << endl;
}
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to output the return value, and just want to keep it for later use, you can do this

```
int main()
{
    string functionOutput = Platin("Trib");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't see anything because you *didn't* say anywhere you wanted to output something. Your line:

```
Platin("Trib");
```

just returns a temporary object (string) that is not used anywhere (and that, of course, is not *displayed*).
In practice, you need to pass the newly string created to the [standard output stream](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/basic_io/), as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string Platin(string x)
 {string ans = x + " 98" ;
    return ans; }

int main()
{
   cout << Platin("Trib") << endl; // <- Instruct your program to output something 
}
```

Comment: Yea i got it now thanks. Used to of programming in java and you don't have to use system.out for getting method output their as far as i remember.

Comment: @slk, Java works the same way. Perhaps you meant [Javascript](http://i.imgur.com/kDATwqI.png).

Comment: @slk Euh, nope.. Java makes use of streams too and doesn't send any information to standard streams if not specifically instructed. Glad it helped!

Comment: Yea you guys are right, i mixed it with writing a system.out statement within the method called. That way you don't see the out stream in main but its there in the method call. I still bad about making such a mistake lol. Thanks everyone